# SSRS multiple condition on textbox

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I am stuck in ssrs scenario where i have to show the `textbox` when it is exported to excel or pdf also I have to hide that in `count("dataset") = 0`

Below is the expression I am using in hidden property of `textbox`

```
=IIF( (Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive) , IIf(CountRows("dataset") > 0 , True, False), False)
```

Comment: Don't you have to turn it around? Right now you are saying to show the textbox when using an interactive renderer. Excel or pdf, is not an interactive renderer

Comment: That was my bad ...I missed that part..thanks @DenStudent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this chages

```
=IIF(Globals!RenderFormat.IsInteractive,True,IIf(CountRows("dataset") > 0 , False, True))
```